# Any book on major (recent) math discovery (results) in an easy understanding way?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, open-problem, book-recommendation

All:

Can anyone recommend a book which illustrate major (recent) math discoveries (results) in an easy understanding way ?

For "recent discoveries", I meaning something discovered in last 50 years.

I used to enjoy a book, Mathematics: Its Content, Methods and Meaning, By: M. A. Lavrent’ev, A. D. Aleksandrov, A. N. Kolmogorov

That is a great book, but it only cover math till 1960s. I am looking for a book in the same style and depth, but covers major math progress in last 50 years.

Answer (score 1):

You might enjoy Piergiorgio Odifreddi, The Mathematical Century: The 30 Greatest Problems of the Last 100 Years, published by [Princeton University Press](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7789.html) in 2006. Also, Ben Yandell, The Honors Class: Hilbert's Problems and Their Solvers, published by AKPeters in 2001. Here's a [link](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/769260.The_Honors_Class) to a review.